# Facebook OAuth Login Success not returning to originating window for IE only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm using new Facebook login:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '@facebookAppId', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth: true
        });
        runFbInitCriticalCode();
    };

    function runFbInitCriticalCode() {
        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
            window.location = "/facebookPostAuth.aspx";
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {

        });

        // Hack to fix http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20168 for IE7/8/9
        FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b) { FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b; };
    }; 

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    } (document));
```

Anyone knows why after the popup login SUCCESS and the login popup closes, the success result does not return to the login page or originator page? This only happens in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the **FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login')** not 100% dependable on IE as it sometimes doesn't hit.

When I'm debugging JavaScript in IE it works. When I'm not debugging with IE Developer tool, it usually fails to hit.

I've set a JavaScript time interval as insurance for IE to check FB token received (this works perfectly since I always get the accesstoken after login successfully even though the login event subscribe doesn't work in IE when not debugging).

Still... If anyone know a why to the question, pls feel free to post.

**UPDATE**

Instead of using the Facebook button that needs to be initialised, I've set up custom anchor/button which calls the log-in function explicitly using JavaScript click event handler. That solves the IE peculiarity and I no longer need a time-interval for checking when the token received. Moreover, I can style it right from the outset, instead of styling over the original FB initialised log-in button.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

On the click event, I call:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     //Token, Login Status can be grabbed from response.authResponse
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to do with the P3P header required for IE.

We always add this header in our projects (which are MVC3 ASP.NET) by doing this:

```
 protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
            // You need this to allow IE to have cross domain cookies and sessions
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("P3P:CP", "IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", FacebookSettings.CurrentConfig().CanvasUrl);
        }
```

You can find more info here:

[Iframe Facebook application and cookies [Internet Explorer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835285/iframe-facebook-application-and-cookies-internet-explorer)