# Logging in using the PHP SDK 3.1.1 & JS not working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

As of this writing, I'm using PHP SDK v3.1.1-12, and I used the same exact example (changing the app id and secret, of course) from this site:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

But it does not work.  Any ideas as to why?  According to the following post:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/

It says there's some issue w/ cookie handling and the new JS SDK; however the post was written back in May--it is now Dec 2011, and somehow it's still not working?

I added a line of PHP code before the closing tag (`?>`):

`var_dump($user);`

And I always get the following output: `int(0)`, even after logging in.

Please note that you must be logged out of facebook, and have deleted all facebook related cookies to recreate this issue.

I've searched all over here and google, and every solution seems to be outdated or doesn't pertain to my issue--I just simply want to have a user log in utilizing the PHP and JS SDKs.

Comment: did you test with IE ? if so, you have to set a special header in php to read the js cookie on php side.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835285/iframe-facebook-application-and-cookies-internet-explorer

Comment: no, I was using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for you in Chrome.  But in Firefox, according to http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20310#c4, the auth.login event fires before cookie data is available.

A workaround is provided at the above URL.