# FaceBook Like Button Login Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am having a problem with the Facebook "Like" button specifically when using Internet Explorer (v10 on Windows 7, but it happens on any version it seems when testing).

The problem only occurs when the user has not already logged into Facebook before in the browser (i.e. presumably a cookie has not already been saved in the browser that they have logged in before to Facebook elsewhere).

When a user clicks the "Like" button they are first presented with a login screen dialog where they must enter their username and password and then what would normally happen after this in any other browser is that the "Like" count would increment and the user would be able to post a comment to their Facebook wall.

However what is happening in Internet Explorer specifically is once the user has logged into Facebook is that the login screen disappears and nothing happens. If the "Like" button is then clicked again what happens is a blank dialog appears which links to a URL which changes (too quickly for me to see) to another URL including **close_popup.php** and then the popup disappears again and nothing happens.

However if I then refresh the page and click the "Like" button again in Internet Explorer it will work as it is supposed to incrementing the "Like" count and allowing the user to post a comment (this time though the user is already logged in from the previous attempt).

I have looked closely at other questions and read the developer documentation, but despite what I have tried, I cannot seem to fix the problem. I would be grateful if anyone could suggest a way that I might fix the issue.

Comment: Perhaps setting a cookie will help (at least it always does for me when dealing with login issues in IE). Take a look at the top answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835285/iframe-facebook-application-and-cookies-internet-explorer